# Simple React component to show sorted articles

Tags: javascript, react.js

I have a basic articles sorting application, the `App` component gets some articles and pass them to the `Articles` component which renders a list of the articles sorted by date or by upvotes.

Each article is an object with `id` (string), `title` (string), `upvotes` (number), and `date` (string format `YYYY-MM-DD`) properties.

By default the articles are shown by upvotes in descending order.

This is the `Articles` component:

```
import React from "react";

function Articles({ articles }) {
  return (
    <div>
      <table>
        <thead>
          <tr>
            <th>Title</th>
            <th>Upvotes</th>
            <th>Date</th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
          {articles.map(({id, title, upvotes, date}) => (
            <tr key={id}>
              <td>{title}</td>
              <td>{upvotes}</td>
              <td>{date}</td>
            </tr>
          ))}
        </tbody>
      </table>
    </div>
  );
}

export default Articles;
```

And this is the `App` component:

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import './App.css';

import Articles from './components/Articles';

function App({ articles }) {

  const sortByUpvotesDesc = (a,b) => b.upvotes - a.upvotes
  const sortByDateDesc = (a,b) => b.date > a.date ? 1 : b.date === a.date ? 0 : -1

  const [articlesOrder, setArticlesOrder] = useState('byUpvotesDesc')

  const mostUpvotedClickHandler = () => {
    setArticlesOrder('byUpvotesDesc')
  }

  const mostRecentClickHandler = () => {
    setArticlesOrder('byDatesDesc')
  }

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <div>
        <label>Sort By</label>
        <button onClick={mostUpvotedClickHandler} >Most Upvoted</button>
        <button onClick={mostRecentClickHandler} >Most Recent</button>
      </div>
      <Articles articles={articles.sort(articlesOrder === 'byUpvotesDesc' ? sortByUpvotesDesc : sortByDateDesc)} />
    </div>
  );

}

export default App;
```

I would appreciate any insights and feedback on how to improve this, especially regarding the `App` component.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Date sorting** Your dates are of the format `YYYY-MM-DD`. You currently sort them with:

```
(a, b) => b.date > a.date ? 1 : b.date === a.date ? 0 : -1
```

When you want to lexiographically compare strings to determine which comes first in the alphabet for sorting, you can do it more concisely with `localeCompare`, which returns a number indicating whether one string comes before, is the same as, or after another. You can use:

```
(a, b) => b.date.localeCompare(a.date);
```

**articlesOrder**'s state relies on, essentially, magic strings:

```
const [articlesOrder, setArticlesOrder] = useState('byUpvotesDesc')
```

Since there are only two possible sorting methods, you might consider using a boolean instead:

```
const [orderByUpvotes, setOrderByUpvotes] = useState(true)
```

If there were more sorting methods, I would feel a bit more comfortable using an enum of sorts (or TypeScript to enforce string comparison safety) than comparing strings like `articlesOrder === 'byUpvotesDesc'` that need to match across multiple places in the code. For example:

```
const SORTING_OPTIONS = {
  byUpvotesDesc: 0,
  byDatesDesc: 1,
  // ...
};
// ...
const [articlesOrder, setArticlesOrder] = useState(SORTING_OPTIONS.byUpvotesDesc);
```

Another option would be to omit the `articlesOrder` variable entirely, and instead only sort the articles when a button is clicked (see below) - but if you want to expand on the component, keeping an `articlesOrder` variable will probably be useful to indicate to the user what the current sorting order is (for example, to give the top container a visual indicator of what option is currently selected).

**Mutation** You are mutating the prop when you do:

```
<Articles articles={articles.sort(articlesOrder === 'byUpvotesDesc' ? sortByUpvotesDesc : sortByDateDesc)} />
```

because `.sort` sorts in-place. Put the prop into state instead, and when a new sort order needs to occur, copy the array before sorting it so as not to mutate. Also, rather than `.sort`ing *every time* the component is rendered, it would be better to sort only when the sort order changes. Here's one possible approach:

```
const sortByUpvotesDesc = (a, b) => b.upvotes - a.upvotes
const sortByDateDesc = (a, b) => b.date.localeCompare(a.date);

function App({ articles: articlesProp }) {
    const [articles, setArticles] = useState(articlesProp);
    const [articlesOrder, setArticlesOrder] = useState();

    const sortArticles = (callback) => {
        setArticles(
            articles => articles.slice().sort(callback)
        );
    };
    // The below could be made more abstract and DRY if there were more options
    // but with only two, it would probably be more confusing than useful
    const mostUpvotedClickHandler = () => {
        sortArticles(sortByUpvotesDesc);
        setArticlesOrder(SORTING_OPTIONS.byUpvotesDesc);
    };
    const mostRecentClickHandler = () => {
        sortArticles(sortByDateDesc);
        setArticlesOrder(SORTING_OPTIONS.byDatesDesc);
    };
    // Sort articles on initial mount, before they're rendered, to avoid reflow:
    useLayoutEffect(mostUpvotedClickHandler, []);

    return (
        <div className="App">
            <div>
                <label>Sort By</label>
                <button onClick={mostUpvotedClickHandler} >Most Upvoted</button>
                <button onClick={mostRecentClickHandler} >Most Recent</button>
            </div>
            <Articles articles={articles} />
        </div>
    );
}
```

**Semicolons** Best to be consistent; either use semicolons or don't. If you're skilled and confident that you won't be bitten by the rules of [ASI](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2846283/what-are-the-rules-for-javascripts-automatic-semicolon-insertion-asi), you can omit them. Use a [linter](https://eslint.org/docs/rules/semi) to enforce your desired style across your codebase.

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to review my code, this is incredibly valuable feedback, I'm internalizing every point you mentioned :D.